# $\sigma$-ring generated by trace is trace of generated $\sigma$-ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> **Theorem**. *If $\mathbf{E}$ is any class of sets and if $\mathit{A}$ is any subset of X, then*
> $$\text{S(E)}\space\cap \mathit{A} =\mathbf{S(E}\space\cap\mathit{A}).  $$ **Proof**. Denote by **C** the class of all sets of the form *B* $\cup $ $(C- \mathit{A})$, where $$B \space \varepsilon\space\mathbf{S(E\space\cap\mathit{A})} \space\text{and}\space C\space\varepsilon\space \mathbf{S(E});$$it is easy to verify that **C** is a $\sigma$-ring.

We are using Paul Halmos's Measure Theory as our textbook. One of the proofs provided is incomplete. I don't like learning things without knowing the full proof. Is there full proof that shows why $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma$-ring?

I know I need to take two sets $G,H$ in $\mathcal C$ and prove that $G-H\in \mathcal C$

But that means I have to show that $(B_G\cup(C_G- A))-(B_H\cup(C_H-A))\in \mathcal C$, which is just too complicated to me. I am not sure how it is easy to verify.

Comment: It certainly isn't easy!!.

Comment: As much as I *hate* the phrase in books, the phrase "...it is easy to verify..." should be understood to mean "Exercise:  verify this claim."  This is the author instructing the reader that they need to complete this exercise on their own, in the same way that the student is expected to complete the exercises at the end of the chapter.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, nobody on this site seems to be able to solve this. So it is not easy. Especialy for a student who is just starting to learn this.

Comment: @Isaac That no one chooses to answer you is completely different from no one on this site knowing how to answer the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, they don't have to provide a full answer. Just a hint on how to start would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If we define $\mathbf{C}$ a bit differently it becomes easier to see that it is a $\sigma$-ring.
To give a better definition, let's aks the question: why do we even care about $\mathbf{C}$?

The answer is that it is easy to see that $\mathbf{E} \subset \mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{C} \cap A = \mathbf{S}(\mathbf{E} \cap A)$, and hence if it is a $\sigma$-ring, $\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{E}) \subset \mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{E})\cap A \subset \mathbf{S}(\mathbf{E} \cap A)$.

A better definition of $\mathbf{C}$ then, is $\mathbf{C} := \{C \subset X\mid C \cap A \in \mathbf{S}(\mathbf{E} \cap A)\}$.

This class of sets truly is easy to verify is a $\sigma$-ring.
For let $C_1,C_2 \in \mathbf{C}$, then

$(C_1-C_2)\cap A = (C_1 \cap A)-(C_2\cap A)$.

And for $\{C_n\} \subset \mathbf{C}$ a countable collection

$\big(\bigcup C_n \big) \cap A = \bigcup \, (C_n \cap A)$.